# "write to file" doesn't work inside if statement

Tags: perl

I have a simple "write to file" in Perl. But the file never write, inside the if statement. It writes, out side the if statement. If condition is always met, and normal print works. Any clue?

```
open (FH, '>>', $files) or die $!;

print FH "outside if, write to file";

if (condition){
    print FH "inside if, write to file";
    print "inside if, normal print";

};
```

output is

```
inside if, normal print
```

File content is

```
outside if, write to file
```

Comment: How do you check? Also, don't forget to [close](http://p3rl.org/close) the filehandle if you're checking the file contents while the script still runs.

Comment: Please show the actual code.  If this is it, you have `if (condition)` (no `$`), which also means that you don't have `use warnings;` (and surely not `use strict;`), which is a bad error.

Comment: I have try the code you post and it working. Please show us a complete code so we can figure out where the problem is.

Comment: You are mistaken, or you are lying about the code you ran or the output it gave. There's no way the second `print` inside the `if` executed but not the second.

Answer (score 6):

Obviousy, `condition` is a function that [ties](https://metacpan.org/pod/perltie) filehandle FH into a package that disables `print`.

Here's a prototype:

```
$files = $ARGV[0];
sub condition { tie *FH, 'print_disabler'; 1 }
sub print_disabler::TIEHANDLE { bless {},shift }
sub print_disabler::PRINT { return }

open (FH, '>>', $files) or die $!;

print FH "outside if, write to file";

if (condition){
    print FH "inside if, write to file";
    print "inside if, normal print";

};

$ perl condition.pl foo
inside if, normal print
$ cat foo
outside if, write to file
```

Comment: very cool just how "obvious" it is :)

Comment: I'll upvote this all day